# Логгирование исключений в Java

Tags: java, логирование

Проблема такова. В классе с точкой входа есть блоки try, catch(эта часть кода приведена ниже). Я в catch пробросил исключения с других классов и хотел бы в блоке catch прологгировать каждое исключение. Посмотрел документацию, прикрутил логгер,но не совсем понимаю как в одном блоке catch в моем случае прологгировать каждое исключение.

```
fileHandler= new FileHandler("Exceptions log.txt");
 public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
                    throws IOException {
                try{
                    MailRepository mailRepository = new MailRepository(dbConnection);
                    MailRepository dataModificator=new MailRepository(dbConnection);
                    MailSender mailSender = new MailSender(dbConnection);
                    List<Message> messageList = mailRepository.GetMessage(messageLimit);
                    while(messageList.size() != 0){
                        messageList = mailRepository.GetMessage(messageLimit);
                        for(int i=0; i<messageList.size();i++){
                            mailSender.send(messageList.get(i));
                            dataModificator.dataModification(Integer.parseInt(messageList.get(i).getId()));
                        }
                    }
                    logger.addHandler(fileHandler);
                    logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
                    logger.info("Start logging");
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException |SQLException | NullPointerException | MessagingException e){

                    logger.log(Level.WARNING, "trouble sneezing", e);
                }
                logger.fine("Exception logged");
            }
        };
```

Comment: Что значит каждое исключение? Когда исключение происходит, происходит только одна какая-то цепочка исключений. В вашем случае если пройзойдёт одно из следующих исключений:
`NumberFormatException | SQLException | NullPointerException | MessagingException` будет выведена информация в лог, со стектрейсом. И `Level.WARNING` не особо уместный для исключений, всё-таки уместнее `Level.ERROR`

Comment: первое исключение в случае ошибке формата данных, второе ошибка при подключении к бд,или если что-то случилось при запросе.3-если какое-то поле объекта сообщения пустое и 4 исключение в случае неполадок в отправке сообщений. как организовать лог,чтобы в случае возникновения ошбки он прописывал в документ,что случилось например SQLException, а не  MessagingException?

Comment: Он и так будет это прописывать, потому что у каждого возникающего исключения есть сообщение, а само исключение вы отдаете методу `log` третьим параметром.

Comment: обновил вопрос. он не показывает какое исключение,только указывает метод,который выдал исключение

Comment: так в том, что вы обновили нет исключений, там как минимум должно быть сообщение `trouble sneezing`, а его нет. то что там вам пишет строка `logger.fine("Exception logged");`, которая вне `catch` блока.
Вы уверены, что в catch блок заходит ваша программа? Проверьте отладчиком.

Comment: да,вы правы. я вызвал AuthenticationFailedException,при котором получил в компиляторе :
мар 23, 2016 12:16:13 PM com.mailer.Reception$1 handleDelivery
WARNING: trouble sneezing
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 m202sm2187251wma.7 - gsmtp
оно является подклассом Messaging Exception. В документ лога ничего не записалось...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html)

```
try {
    MailRepository mailRepository = new MailRepository(dbConnection);
    MailRepository dataModificator=new MailRepository(dbConnection);
    MailSender mailSender = new MailSender(dbConnection);
    List<Message> messageList = mailRepository.GetMessage(messageLimit);
    while(messageList.size() != 0){
        messageList = mailRepository.GetMessage(messageLimit);
        for(int i=0; i<messageList.size();i++){
            mailSender.send(messageList.get(i));
            dataModificator.dataModification(Integer.parseInt(messageList.get(i).getId()));
        }
    }
    logger.addHandler(fileHandler);
    logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    logger.info("Start logging");
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, "trouble sneezing", e);
} catch (SQLException name) {
    // обработка всех остальных эксепшенов по аналогии
}
...
logger.fine("Exception logged");
```

Comment: в документации написано,что можно в 1 блоке catch обработать несколько исключений
' catch (IOException|SQLException ex) {
    logger.log(ex);
    throw ex;
} '
разве в моем случае так сделать нельзя?